# Creating a Conditional Function in Python

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a tax deductions calculation function in python based on a series of conditional statements. I am getting a syntax error on my first conditional "if" statement and am unsure why.

```
1 = 'single'
2 = 'married filing jointly'
3 = 'head of household'

def deductions(income, filing_category): ## define function

    if ((filing_category = 1) and (income >= 12200)):
        return income - 12200
    elif((filing_category = 2) and (income >= 24400)):
        return income - 24400
    elif((filing_category = 3) and (income >= 18350)):
        return income - 18350
    else:
        return 'no taxes due'

q = deductions(10000, 1) ## call function
print(q) ## print result
```

If anyone could offer any insight into what syntactical errors I may be making, that would be great. I'm a beginner to programming.

Comment: Use '==' instead of '=' in if condition.

Comment: Have you hear about `==` before? You have to use that inside `if` to check equality. Further, `1 = 'single'` can't be a valid syntax in any language

Answer (score 3):

Replace `filing_category = 1` with `filing_category == 1`. Do this for other instances of `=` in your `if` statements.

The single `=` is the assignment operator, assigning a value to a variable. The equality operator, which tests if two things are equal, is `==`. Refer to the [python documentation on operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) for more information.